# How to Create a New Lead in SalesForce Using TwilioForce APEX Library

Tags: salesforce, twilio, force.com

Good Morning All,

First and foremost, the Force.com IDE and Salesforce is a new skillset for me.  I'm attempting to utilize the TwilioForce APEX Library: https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/install

to create a new Salesforce Lead for each incoming call on my client's Twilio account.  I've gotten as far as creating a new Force.com project in Eclipse, copying the Twilioforce components, classes and pages to the project, but need some guidance in how to write the logic to create the lead.

Questions I have:
1.  Can you provide links to reference material demonstrating how to create a new lead in Salesforce programmtically?
2.  How do I test the TwilioForce components, especially those I've changed to reflect my client's Twilio phone number and token?  Are these callable from within the Force.com Project in Eclipse, or must they be called from my developer.org account?
3.  Once I figure out how to accomplish the above lead creation from incoming Twilio calls, how do I deploy the codebase I've created to my client?

Thanks,
Sid

EDIT:
EyeScream, your sample was a huge help.  Here's the TwilioRestResponse class that came with the TwilioForce codebase:

```
public class TwilioRestResponse {

private String responseText;
private integer httpStatus;
private String url;
private String queryString;
private boolean error;


public TwilioRestResponse(String url, String text, integer status){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile('([^?]+)\\??(.*)');
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    m.matches();
    this.url = m.group(1);
    this.queryString = m.group(2);
    this.responseText = text;
    this.httpStatus=status;
    this.error = (status>=400);  
}

// getters and setters 
public String getResponseText() {
    return responseText;
}
public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
    this.responseText = responseText;
}
public integer getHttpStatus() {
    return httpStatus;
}
public void setHttpStatus(integer httpStatus) {
    this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public String getQueryString() {
    return queryString;
}
public void setQueryString(String queryString) {
    this.queryString = queryString;
}
public boolean isError() {
    return error;
}
public void setError(boolean error) {
    this.error = error;
}   
}
```

There's also a CallsXmlParser class as follows:

```
public class CallsXmlParser{
//All Parsed records will be in this list
public List<Call> listRecords = new List<Call>();
//Data Model to store all response elements
public class Call{
    public string Sid{get;set;}
    public string DateCreated{get;set;}
    public string DateUpdated{get;set;}
    public string CallSegmentSid{get;set;}
    public string AccountSid{get;set;}
    public string Called{get;set;}
    public string Caller{get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumberSid{get;set;}
    public string Status{get;set;}
    public string StartTime{get;set;}
    public string EndTime{get;set;}
    public string Duration{get;set;}
    public string Price{get;set;}
    public string Flags{get;set;}
    public string Annotation{get;set;}
}
public CallsXmlParser(){

}
public CallsXmlParser(string data){
    XmlStreamReader xsr = new XmlStreamReader(data);
    listRecords = parse(xsr);
}
public Call[] parse(XmlStreamReader reader) {
    Call[] members = new Call[0];
    while(reader.hasNext()) {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT) {
           if ('Call' == reader.getLocalName()) {                 
                Call member = parseMember(reader);
                members.add(member);
            }
         }
        reader.next();
    }
    return members;
}
//Parsing Each Call Tag and its nested tags
public Call parseMember(XmlStreamReader reader){
    Call callObject = new Call();
    while(reader.hasNext()) {

       if ('Call' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.END_ELEMENT) {
           break;
        }
        else if('Sid' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Sid = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('DateCreated' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.DateCreated= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('DateUpdated' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.DateUpdated= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('CallSegmentSid' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.CallSegmentSid= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('AccountSid' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.AccountSid= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Called' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Called= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Caller' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Caller= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('PhoneNumberSid' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.PhoneNumberSid= reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Status' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Status = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('StartTime' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.StartTime = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('EndTime' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.EndTime = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Duration' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Duration = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Price' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Price = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Flags' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Flags = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }else if('Annotation' == reader.getLocalName() && reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT){
          reader.next();                   
          if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.CHARACTERS) { 
            callObject.Annotation = reader.getText(); 
          }
        }

       reader.next();
   }
   return callObject;
} 
}
```

My very basic insertLead class is as follows:

```
public with sharing class insertLead {
Lead1 = new Lead(Phone='TwilioRestResponse.GetResponseText');
}
```

I need to read in the Phone number and CallerID Name from either the TwilioRestResponse or the CallXmlParser classes and insert into the appropriate fields in a new Lead.
What is the appropriate syntax for referencing the CallObject.PhoneNumberSid in my new Lead?  Alternatively, is it better to parse out the TwilioRestResponse?  If so, how would I select just the phone number and CallerID Name from the GetResponseText?

Thanks again,
Sid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer updated, please scroll down**

```
public class SidTest {

    //  1. How to create a new Lead programatically on Force.com (in Apex)
    /* This method is marked as test method, meaning that you can use it to run tests but in the end no data will be saved
        (transaction rollback). You'll need similar code in a class that intercepts messages from Twilio.
    */
    public static testMethod void insertLead(){
        Lead l = new Lead(FirstName='Test', LastName='Lead', Email='example@example.com', Company='test', NumberofEmployees=7);
        insert l;

        // 2. How do I test the TwilioForce components, especially those I've changed to reflect my client's Twilio phone number and token?
    /*  Not sure what do you mean, but most likely by writing test classes like this one and checking their test code coverage.
        See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372202/how-to-unit-test-works-in-salesforce/4381941
        Below sample test that checks if our insert above succeeded.
        You can run it from Eclipse (preferred) or Salesforce GUI in Setup->Develop->Apex classes.
    */
        Lead[] leads = [SELECT Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE Name = 'Test Lead'];

        System.debug(leads);    // if you want to see results in detailed debug log
        System.assertEquals(1, leads.size());
        System.assertEquals('example@example.com', leads[0].Email);
    }
}
```

Here's the outcome when you'll run it in Eclipse: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709568/stackoverflow/Sid.png

As for last question: when you'll be happy with functionality tested in your Developer Edition, you should ask client to grant you access to "Sandbox" of his organisation. You can create in Eclipse a new project pointing to this sandbox and simply create all classes in it, run tests with a subset of real data etc. Finally you or somebody from client's side will perform a deployment to "production" environment where stuff like code coverage in automated tests will start to matter.

Alternatively you could create a package with your code and sell it on AppExchange like a plugin to Salesforce that anybody can download to their organisation. You can charge for it of course. But this looks like a too big jump for now...

Hope this can get you started.

---

**Update:**
Here's a quick & dirty class based on TestCallsXmlParser that's included in code package you are using:

```
public class TestCallsXmlParser{
    @isTest
    public static void TestCallsXmlParserMethod1(){
        CallsXmlParser callxml = new CallsXmlParser();
        String xmlData = '<TwilioResponse> <Calls page=\"0\" numpages=\"1\" pagesize=\"50\" total=\"38\" start=\"0\" end=\"37\"> <Call> <Sid>CA42ed11f93dc08b952027ffbc406d0868</Sid> <DateCreated>Sat, 07 Feb 2009 13:15:19 -0800</DateCreated><DateUpdated>Sat, 07 Feb 2009 13:15:19 -0800</DateUpdated><CallSegmentSid/>';
        xmlData = xmlData + '<AccountSid>AC309475e5fede1b49e100272a8640f438</AccountSid><Called>4159633717</Called><Caller>4156767925</Caller><PhoneNumberSid>PN01234567890123456789012345678900</PhoneNumberSid><Status>2</Status><StartTime>Thu, 03 Apr 2008 04:36:33 -0400</StartTime><EndTime>Thu, 03 Apr 2008 04:36:47 -0400</EndTime>';
        xmlData = xmlData + '<Duration>14</Duration><Price/><Flags>1</Flags></Call>';
        xmlData = xmlData + '<Call><Sid>CA751e8fa0a0105cf26a0d7a9775fb4bfb</Sid><DateCreated>Sat, 07 Feb 2009 13:15:19 -0800</DateCreated><DateUpdated>Sat, 07 Feb 2009 13:15:19 -0800</DateUpdated><CallSegmentSid/>';
        xmlData = xmlData + '<AccountSid>AC309475e5fede1b49e100272a8640f438</AccountSid><Called>2064287985</Called><Caller>4156767925</Caller><PhoneNumberSid>PNd59c2ba27ef48264773edb90476d1674</PhoneNumberSid><Status>2</Status>';
        xmlData = xmlData + '<StartTime>Thu, 03 Apr 2008 01:37:05 -0400</StartTime><EndTime>Thu, 03 Apr 2008 01:37:40 -0400</EndTime><Duration>35</Duration><Price/> <Flags>1</Flags> </Call></Calls></TwilioResponse> ';
        CallsXmlParser callxml1 = new CallsXmlParser(xmlData);

        // eyescream's modification starts here

        // list to store our leads and bulk save them in blocks up to 100 records at 1 insert
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();

        for(CallsXmlParser.Call c : callxml1.listRecords) {
            System.debug('2 new Leads will be created from phone numbers: ' + c.Caller + ', ' + c.Called);
            leads.add(new Lead(MobilePhone = c.Caller, Company='x', LastName='x')); // Company & Last Name are mandatory fields
            leads.add(new Lead(MobilePhone = c.Called, Company='y', LastName='y')); // without them insert will fail.

            if(leads.size() == 100) { // 100 is the limit of records saved at once. Inserting in batches speeds up execution.
                insert leads;
                leads.clear();
            }
        }

        // If we have any leftovers, we'll insert them too.
        if(leads.size() > 0) {
            insert leads;
            leads.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can improve it further, check for duplicates, fill with real names etc... but that's roughly how you can use parsed results. I don't think that parsing the XML yourself would be a good option... Your question suggests that more fields will come in the XML (or existing ones will be used to store different data) but probably you'll be able to expand the parser accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a compile error on the line for (CallsXmlParser.Call c : callxml1.ListRecords){
stating expecting right curly bracket

Comment: I've just created in my org 2 classes from Twilio library: TestCallsXmlParser and CallsXmlParser. Both in latest versions from trunk and it runs without problems... Maybe you made a typo in class names? Is the inner class Calls a public one? Maybe your version of eclipse/force.com plugin is old? I'm on plugin version Summer '10 (19.0.0) and my full codebase is here for reference: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/709568/stackoverflow/Sid%20-%20my%20Dev%20Edition.zip

Comment: My bad:)  I was missing a right curly bracket at the very end of the file.  Now that this is created, how do I go about running it on my developerforce account?  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Right click it in the left menu (with "classes" directory etc., like the one you can see on my screenshot), then Force.com->Run tests. Or right click whole "classes" dir. Now... This is just a example, your "real" code will have to be split into class that actually reads XML and inserts leads and a second (test) class used only in unit testing... but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have problem in deploying twilio library here are good details provided, which do most of the tasks. Some how if it could help http://redcurrantscloud.blogspot.in/

Thanks.