# Unit Testing in SalesForce

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code

I found a similar answer here:

[How to unit test works in salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372202/how-to-unit-test-works-in-salesforce)

and here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

But those didn't really seem to answer my particular question.

I "stubbed out" some test classes. We *should have* been doing this from the beginning, but they handed a group of developers a SalesForce project who have never done SalesForce before...then put us on a time crunch. They told us at the time not to worry about unit testing, and now we find out that SalesForce requires 75% or greater code coverage in order to be in production.

Anyway, I know I can test for state in methods that return void, and I know I can test the return type of methods that have them.

But my question is: How do I test values that are supposed to be input through a VisualForce page? Do I just create the class and fill in the info?

I'm much more familiar with Unit Testing in C#, to the point where I use Roy Osherove's test method naming convention, or at least my version of it.

Additionally, how would I test pages that have a querystring? I'm assuming I would do a PageReference with some kind of query string, but unit tests, in general, should run independently.

My main concern is running the tests dynamically (i.e. dynamic record IDs), and what happens if there are no records (i.e. if the dev/testing environment get wiped).

So, thoughts on this?

Comment: See if the information in this link is the right direction: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

Comment: I've noted that one in my above post. I will look deeper into it, but I don't know if that will do what I need.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice that one. I don't have much advice since all the code I deal with in apex is for triggers. All I know is that you need to create fake data in each test method. Maybe you can create variables in the test method(s) that simulate values that may have come from a visualforce page. And, if I'm understanding correctly, I don't think you need to have tests for visualforce pages, just actual class code. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't test the Visualforce page, you test the controller. You can create an instance of your controller in the test, feed it the data you need (parameters) and directly call the methods in the controller.

```
MyPageController ctrl = new MyPageController(params)
ctrl.loadData();
ctrl.saveInput();
ctrl.alertUser();
```

It is best practice to use a testUtils class that ceates dummy data for your tests. Then just call the appropriate methods from your test class.

```
List<Contact> contacts = testUtils.createContacts();
insert contacts;
```

Any trigger that works on insert will be fired, and you get your code coverage. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Do not refer to existing records in Apex test classes. Create your own test data in the test class and then refer to it in test methods.

You can set parameters as below:

PageReference startPage = new PageReference('/apex/VisualforcePageName?id='+record.id);
Test.setCurrentPage(startPage);

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_data